# AttributeError: 'RandomOverSampler' object has no attribute 'fit_sample'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imblearn

I am trying to use RandomOverSampler from imblearn but I'm getting error.

Looking at other posts, there seems to be a problem with older versions, but I checked my versions and I have:

```
sklearn.__version__
'0.24.1'

imblearn.__version__
'0.8.0'
```

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler

OS = RandomOverSampler(sampling_strategy='auto', random_state=0)
osx, osy = OS.fit_sample(X, y)
```

And the error I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-a080b92fc7bc> in <module>
      2 
      3 OS = RandomOverSampler(sampling_strategy='auto', random_state=0)
----> 4 osx, osy = OS.fit_sample(X, y)

AttributeError: 'RandomOverSampler' object has no attribute 'fit_sample'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `OS.fit_resample(X, y)`, not `fit_sample`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- install the library:

```
pip install imbalanced-learn
```

- usage example:

```py
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler

oversample = RandomOverSampler(sampling_strategy='minority')
X_over, y_over = oversample.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score -2):

You want OS.fit_resample(X, y), not fit_resample.

Comment: You meant `fit_sample` not `fit_resample` no? And overall what is your answer different from @Tim Roberts ?